# only rendering last X lines of chunk output in R Markdown

Tags: r, shell, r-markdown

I am calling a shell program from R Markdown like this

````
```{sh}
SomeShellProgram -options
```
````

and render the file as HTML. The calculation the program does take some time, wherefore the author included an self-updating progress "bar" which looks something like this:

> 45Mb   12.4% 935 OTUs, 3485 chimeras (6.7%)

However, especially if the progress is slow, it will update this line every 0.1% or so. And each line is rendered separately in the HTML, which can ad up to up to 1000 lines of progress bars.

**I don't want to suppress the output completely** , e.g. with `echo=FALSE` in the chunk options. I am producing a report and the information that is printed is important.

I am looking for a hack that would somehow only capture the last X lines and render these, or maybe using `grep` or something similar to only capture the lines that have `100%` or so.

I tried redirecting the output with `> output.txt` but the progress wasn't printed to the file (although other information was).

I can't think of a way to provide a reproducible example without giving the full example, sorry for that.

For those that are interested: I am trying to produce a report on the analysis of 16S Illumina sequencing data and I'm using `Usearch` and the command that gives me the most headaches is the `usearch -cluster_otus` command.

**UPDATE**

There is an additional problem with rendering the last X lines: The progress bar in the output is delimited by `^M`(carriage return characters) and not by line breaks, so `less`only recognises it as a single line. Therefore my final solution includes

1. redirecting the output from the progress bar with `2>` into a file
2. replacing the `^M`characters with line breaks using `sed`
3. rendering the last X lines with `less`

My (pseudo)code to do this on mac osx is the following (where X = number of lines)

```
FunctionWithProgressBar -option 2> tempfile.tmp
sed -ibak $'s/\x0D/\\\n/g' tempfile.tmp
tail -nX tempfile.tmp
```

and **in R Markdown**:

````
```{sh, results="hide"}
FunctionWithProgressBar -option 2> tempfile.tmp
```
```{sh, echo=FALSE}
sed -ibak $'s/\x0D/\\\n/g' tempfile.tmp
tail -nX tempfile.tmp
```
````

note that matching the backspace is a pain in the butt (especially on osx) and changes between platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress bar is probably in the sterr stream, so you capture it with "2>" and not ">" so you could capture stderr and stdout separately, e.g.:

```
usearch blablabla 2> only_err > only_stdout
```

Or if you want all of the output together, you have to redirect stderr to stdout, and do an append, as such:

```
usearch blablabla >> total_output 2>&1
```

As for the R-markdown part, I cannot really help, never used, sorry.

regards,

Moritz

Comment: thanks Moritz, it works perfectly. I just need to redirect the `2>` to a file and then I can print only the last line with `tail file`. Markdown will print everything that is printed to the console and as nothing is printed to console if I redirect the steer stream it works perfectly!